# Change pytest capturing for one test

Tags: python, pytest

Is it possible to change the capturing behavior in pytest for just one test — i.e., within the test script?

I have a bunch of tests that I use with [`pytest`](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/).  There are several useful quantities that I like to print during some tests, so I use the `-s` flag to show them in the `pytest` output.  But I also test for warnings, which also get printed, and look ugly and distracting.  I've tried using the [`warnings.simplefilter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/warnings.html) as usual to just not show the warnings, but that doesn't seem to do anything.  (Maybe `pytest` hacks it???)  Anyway, I'd like some way to quiet the warnings but still check that they are raised, while also being able to see the captured output from my other print statements.  Is there any way to do this — e.g., by change the capture for just one test function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it by manually redirecting `stderr`:

```
import os
import sys
import warnings
import pytest

def test():
    stderr = sys.stderr
    sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')
    with pytest.warns(UserWarning):
        warnings.warn("Warning!", UserWarning)
    sys.stderr = stderr
```

For good measure, I could similarly redirect `stdout` to devnull, if other print statements are not wanted.

Answer (score 2):

With pytest 3.x there is an [easy way](http://doc.pytest.org/en/features/capture.html#accessing-captured-output-from-a-test-function) to temporarily disable capturing (see the section about `capsys.disabled()`.

There's also the [pytest-warnings](https://github.com/fschulze/pytest-warnings) plugin which shows the warning in a dedicated report section.

Comment: Thanks for pointing those out; they both look great.  I tried installing from github, but it says `capsys` has no `disabled` attribute.  Must be pretty bleeding-edge!  :)

Comment: The `master` branch is for stable releases, so to see what's [upcoming in 3.0](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/features/CHANGELOG.rst) (a lot!) you'll need to use the `features` branch.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thank you.